# How to create a TweenLite but not start it immediately

Tags: gsap

I can create a TweenLite like this:

```
var tl = TweenLite.from('.box',1,{opacity:0});
```

At this point it automatically plays.

How can I get it to not auto-play, but instead "manually" start it at a later time with:

```
tl.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to the GreenSock Forum moderator who came up with this answer:

```
// put "paused:true" when creating the tween
var tl = TweenLite.from('.box',1,{ opacity:0, paused:true });
```